# What is the maximum size of Google source repository?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I have a file of size 5GB which I want to put it in the GCP source repository. I am unable to do so.

Comment: Please show what you have tried?

Comment: I have created an API with machine language model which  consists of all the  dependency packages and model which is required to run the model, as a result, it crossed to  5 GB approx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This says](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits#google_cloud_source_repositories) that for the free tier the limit is 1GB for each repository, and [this says](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/pricing) you get 50GB total for all repositories.

However, 1GB is a lot of space, and git is generally used for source code only, not compiled code or things that can be re-constructed or re-downloaded. See the discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192113/do-i-check-generated-code-in-to-source-control-or-not?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231201/should-i-use-git-for-project-files-other-than-the-actual-source?noredirect=1&lq=1) (and linked answers on those pages).  Perhaps you might like to check out the following to try and reduce the size of your repo:

- Git Large File Storage (link for [Google specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865110/git-large-file-storage-with-google-cloud-storage)).
- Use a package manager for the language that you are using, to install plugins and packages of the third-party code.
- Use `.gitignore` to exclude build artifacts that you can reproduce with the source code.
- If it's just one file, why use git at all? You could upload to another cloud file host, such as Google Drive or Dropbox.